# How to call plugin in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

**- How to call plugin in cakephp please answer me asap.and how to use it
   i am using code in my app controller   so its giving me error **

```
public function admin_edit_comment() {
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
            $this->autoRender = false;
            if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
                if ($this->FaComment->save($this->request->data, false)) {
                    $response['status'] = 'success';
                    $response['action'] = 'edit_comment';
                    $response['data'] = $this->request->data['FaComment'];
                    $response['message'] = __d('vanderdeals', 'Comment saved successfully');
                } else {
                    $response['status'] = 'error';
                    $response['model'] = 'FaComment';
                    $response['message'] = __d('vanderdeals', 'Internal server error occurred. Please try again later.');
                }

                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this **Goto app/config/bootstrap.php**

```
CakePlugin::loadAll(); // Loads all plugins at once
CakePlugin::load('ContactManager'); // Loads a single plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the wiki on http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins/how-to-use-plugins.html

> Plugin Configuration :There is a lot you can do with the load and
>   loadAll methods to help with plugin configuration and routing. Perhaps
>   you want to load all plugins automatically, while specifying custom
>   routes and bootstrap files for certain plugins.
>
> No problem:

```
CakePlugin::loadAll(array(
    'Blog' => array('routes' => true),
    'ContactManager' => array('bootstrap' => true),
    'WebmasterTools' => array('bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true),
));
```

> With this style of configuration, you no longer need to manually
>   include() or require() a plugin’s configuration or routes file–It
>   happens automatically at the right time and place. The exact same
>   parameters could have also been supplied to the load() method, which
>   would have loaded only those three plugins, and not the rest.